Is there a way to listen to an apple podcast show, one episode after another continuously , newest to oldest?
I recently subscribed to an a podcast on my iPhone 15 pro using the native Apple Podcast App.  The podcast is one from the Apple supplied shows.  Im trying to figure out how to listen to the episodes of the show, continuously , newest to oldest.  There is a sort order option in settings, newest to oldest / oldest to newest - but - the app will only play oldest to newest NOT newest to oldest.  Is there a way to accomplish newest to oldest?  iOS 17.6.1

While I have not been able to accomplish the above with apple, the Downcast app does it perfectly.
